# No compiling Error but crashes when given input

Tags: c, arrays, struct, crash, scanf

This is a program that's suppose to create an array each time addscore is called it adds one to the end of the array. The rest are self explanatory. Scanf seems to be my problem of crash though i am not sure why it is. As my program still crashes after i give option the value 2 without using scanf.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
int deflen;
typedef struct gamedata
{
   int score;
}gamedata;
typedef enum boolean {false,true} boolean;

int addscore(struct gamedata scoreArray[])
{
    int newscore;
    realloc(scoreArray,deflen);
    scanf("%d",scoreArray[deflen-1].score);
    return 0;
}
int printscore(struct gamedata scoreArray[])
{
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x <deflen;x++)
    {
        printf("Player%d, score:%d \n",x+1,scoreArray[x].score);
    }
    return 0;
}
int findhighest(struct gamedata scoreArray[])
{
    int x;
    int high;
    high = 0;
    for (x=0;x<deflen;x++)
    {
        if (scoreArray[x].score > high){
            high = scoreArray[x].score;
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    }
    return high;
}
int findavg(struct gamedata scoreArray[])
{
    int x;
    int sum=0;
    int maxLen = deflen;
    int avg = 0;
    for (x = 0; x <maxLen;x++)
    {
        sum = sum + scoreArray[x].score;
    }
    avg = sum/maxLen;
    return avg;
}
int main()
{
    boolean programEnd = false;
    deflen = 10;
    gamedata scoreArray[deflen];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int x = 0 ; x<deflen ;x++)
    {
        scoreArray[x].score = rand() % 20;
        printf("%d",scoreArray[x].score);
    }
    char option;

    do{
        printf("Please enter an option number: \n"); // this is pretty much what this program is suppose to do.
        printf("1.Add a score: \n");
        printf("2.Output all score: \n");
        printf("3.Find the highest score: \n");
        printf("4.Find the average score: \n");
        printf("5.End program \n");
        ///scanf("%s",&option);
        option = '2';
        printf("%s",option);
        switch(option) {
            case '1' :
                printf("1 step in");
                deflen = deflen + 1;
                addscore(scoreArray);
            break;
            case '2' :
                printf("2 step in");
                printscore(scoreArray);
            break;
            case '3' :
                printf("3 step in");
                printf("high score is  %d \n",findhighest(scoreArray));
            break;
            case '4' :
                printf("4 step in");
                printf("the average score is %d \n",findavg(scoreArray));
            break;
            case '5' :
                printf("5 step in");
                programEnd = true;
            break;
        }
    }while (programEnd == false);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("%s",option);` --> `printf("%c\n",option);`

Comment: Also `scanf("%s",&option);` --> `scanf(" %c", &option);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A program should use realloc() only to **resize dynamically allocated** arrays!!!

[Read this.](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/VOID+Use+realloc%28%29+only+to+resize+dynamically+allocated+arrays)

change the array to be :

```
gamedata** scoreArray=malloc(deflen*sizeof(gamedata));

for(int i=0;i<deflen;i++)
     scoreArray[i]=malloc(sizeof(gamedata));
```

and the realloc need to be:

```
   scoreArray=realloc(scoreArray,deflen)
```

Comment: Your link is broken :)

Comment: Where did the pointer to pointer come from? This `gamedata** addscore(gamedata** scoreArray)` is complete nonsense!